# how to check length of "concatenate" string

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

Has anybody an idea how to write a query in Oracle to get length of characters:

```
|  user   |    action   |
-------------------------
|  mary   |  aaa        |    # 3 characters from action
|  mary   |  bbbbb      |    # 5 characters from action
|  mary   |  c          |    # 1 character from action
|  adam   |  xx         |    # 2 characters from action
|  adam   |  yyyy       |    # 4 characters from action
|  adam   |  zzzzzzz    |    # 7 characters from action
```

So in result should be sum of characters for each:

```
|  mary |    9    |
|  adam |   13    |
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SUM + LENGTH` along with `GROUP BY` user. Sample data in lines #1 - 14; query you need begins at line #15.

```
SQL> WITH
  2     test (cuser, action)
  3     AS
  4        (SELECT 'mary', 'aaa' FROM DUAL
  5         UNION ALL
  6         SELECT 'mary', 'bbbbb' FROM DUAL
  7         UNION ALL
  8         SELECT 'mary', 'c' FROM DUAL
  9         UNION ALL
 10         SELECT 'adam', 'xx' FROM DUAL
 11         UNION ALL
 12         SELECT 'adam', 'yyyy' FROM DUAL
 13         UNION ALL
 14         SELECT 'adam', 'zzzzzzz' FROM DUAL)
 15    SELECT cuser, SUM (LENGTH (action))
 16      FROM test
 17  GROUP BY cuser;

CUSE SUM(LENGTH(ACTION))
---- -------------------
mary                   9
adam                  13

SQL>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `LENGTH` function in your aggregation:

```sql
SELECT "USER",
       SUM( LENGTH( action ) ) AS total_length
FROM   table_name
GROUP BY "USER"
```

Which, for your sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name( "USER", action ) AS
SELECT 'mary', 'aaa'     FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'mary', 'bbbbb'   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'mary', 'c'       FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'adam', 'xx'      FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'adam', 'yyyy'    FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'adam', 'zzzzzzz' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> ```
> USER | TOTAL_LENGTH
> :--- | -----------:
> mary |            9
> adam |           13
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=6cc9a46cb7e4d7afb510393870892ae6)*